# How to remove selection from SELECT created with Html.DropDownList()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a SELECT created in this way:

```
Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities, "Id", "Name"), "(select a city)");
```

I know that the right way is to pass the data using a Model and create the SelectList server side but this is the current situation.
To be clear, the page does not use a Model at all.
The View is served as `return this.View("MyView");`.

The ASP.Net Engine automatically maintains the selection over postbacks.
There is a "Reset" button in the page that in the Controller set hte fields used in the form (data is passed through the ViewBag) the the default value.

The problem is that **I don't know how to remove the selection for that DropDownList** in a simple way. 
I think I can use a SelectedCity property in the ViewBag and change the code like this:

```
Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities, "Id", "Name", ViewBag.SelectedCity), "(select a city)");
```

But:

1. I tried using "null" `(new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities, "Id", "Name", null))` and it does not work.
2. I don't want to introduce a new variable.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Are you making that "reset" by a form submit Post? Or how are you doing it?

Comment: You have a **Reset** button that set the all the controls to the default values or empty from server. Then where is the issue ? You can bind `ViewBag.Cities` there again so that when the page will reload, it will bind again with default value.

Comment: The reset is done by a POST (the page contains a button with submit="reset").
The event is recognized by ```this.Request.Form["reset"] != null``` ..

Comment: On the "reset" event (server side) the ViewBag.Cities is loaded from scratch (actually a new request to the repository) but the DropDownList maintain the selection (this is how ASP.Net works, the ViewState does not know that the colelction was reloaded and the selection was "reset").

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
<%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "poste", @onchange = "test3()" })%>
```

Into your function (test3 in this case) add code for resetting, removing, etc.

[Source](https://forums.asp.net/t/1910044.aspx?How%20to%20remove%20an%20item%20from%20a%20DropDownList%20basing%20on%20the%20item%20selected%20in%20another%20DropDownList%20in%20ASP%20MVC%20and%20using%20Javascript).

Comment: The page is not using a Model at all.

Comment: Yes. I posted that as an example. And add source to page from i've copied that code. Just to help this dude.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are doing the reset by a submit form post and still returning the same "model" on that action the same view, then try to add the following line after your code:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: The page is not using a Model at all.